# AngularJs [$parse:syntax] Error in ui-grid with certain data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, string, angular-ui-grid, brackets

When I try to create an AngularJS ui-grid table with data that contains a '(' and then whitespace before the closing ')' inside a string, then I get an AngularJS error saying:

> Syntax Error: Token '32' is unexpected, expecting [)] at column 22 of the expression [entity[''](trimpoint 32h)] starting at [32h].

Here is the complete HTML code that I am trying to use to create the table:

```
<html> <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/3.2.5/ui-grid.css" /> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/3.2.5/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var app = angular.module('MyGridApp', ['ui.grid']);

app.controller('bodyController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.myData = [{'(trimpoint 32h)': "Moroni", age: 50},
                     {'(trimpoint 32h)': "Tiancum", age: 43},
                     {'(trimpoint 32h)': "Jacob", age: 27}];
    $scope.gridOptions = { data : 'myData' }; }]);

    </script> </head> <body ng-app="MyGridApp" ng-controller="bodyController">
    <div ui-grid="gridOptions">
    </div> </body> </html>
```

If I replace the round brackets with square brackets, then it works fine and the table is rendered i.e:

```
$scope.myData = [{'[trimpoint 32h]': "Moroni", age: 50},
                 {'[trimpoint 32h]': "Tiancum", age: 43},
                 {'[trimpoint 32h]': "Jacob", age: 27}];
```

Is there any reason why AngularJS shows an error while trying to parse this data? It seems like a valid JavaScript string to use as an object name. Thanks

Comment: what happens if you use a backslash with your parenthesis ? `\( random text \)`

Comment: also, could you too try `$scope.gridOptions = { data : $scope.myData };` ?

Comment: Hi @trichetriche, thanks for your response. Same "parse syntax" error with both suggestions unfortunately.

Comment: Could you post your full error as a screenshot or in plain text please ?

Comment: angular.js:10023 Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.21/$parse/syntax?p0=32&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B)%5D&p2=22&p3=entity%5B''%5D(trimpoint%2032h)&p4=32h)
    at angular.js:36
    at cb.throwError (angular.js:10496)
    at cb.consume (angular.js:10530)
    at cb.functionCall (angular.js:10777)
    at cb.primary (angular.js:10480)
    at cb.unary (angular.js:10719)
    at cb.multiplicative (angular.js:10702)
    at cb.additive (angular.js:10693)
    at cb.relational (angular.js:10684)
    at cb.equality (angular.js:10675)

Comment: Sorry for the un-formatted text above. This is shown in the console in Chrome

Comment: Okay, could you try to put a Blank space before your `(` ? (A blank space is Alt + 255 on Windows, or space+space with command key on Linux)

Comment: Sorry @trichetriche, I'm not sure if I understand. I am using Gedit on Ubuntu.

Comment: Well first of all, get used to sublime text, it will change your life. Secondly, ubuntu has a Command key that you can set in the settings. Otherwise, try to copy that space bewteen the brackets : `{ }`. FYI, it's not a spacebar space, but a plain blank space, which is considered as a letter. Or you can type `Ctrl + Shift + U`, keep `Ctrl + Shift` pressed, and type `00A0` for it. When you have it, put it before your `(` in your objects.

Comment: see this thread for more information : http://askubuntu.com/questions/88347/how-can-i-type-ascii-characters-like-alt-numpad-in-windows

Comment: Ok, that helped, thanks. I found the character by copying from the "Character Map" in Ubuntu into Gedit. I had to place the "No break space" character before each of the '(' and after each of the last ')', and then it showed correctly. Is this expected behaviour from JavaScript/AngularJS parser then?

Comment: Frankly I'm not sure, I have never used angular-ui-grid. I just corrected your error, because this kind of error shows when you mispell a function. I guess Angular thuoght you were trying to use a function. I am replying to your topic, could you please mark it as resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the problem is that you need to put a non blank space before each parenthesis.

You can take this one `{ }` or use a unicode character, also try `Alt + 255` on Windows, Or you can type `Ctrl + Shift + U`, keep `Ctrl + Shift` pressed, and type `00A0` for it on Linux. Also, opening characters map might help too.